# Set different limits for scale_fill_gradient in the same ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have code to ggplot:

```
df=data.frame(time=as.factor(rep(0.5:9.5,each=10)),roi=rep(1:10,10),area=runif(100, 5.0, 7.5))
df$time <- factor(df$time, levels=rev(levels(df$time)))
  p1 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(roi), y=time, fill = area)) +
    theme_minimal()  + coord_fixed(ratio=1) +
    geom_tile(colour = "white", width = 1.0, height = 1) + 
    scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red")
```

In the code above, the "blue" and "red" color refers to the lowest and highest values, respectively, of the column of "area". But I want to plot "area" from each "time" value with it own gradient range (it means for example "time" at 0.5, the gradient range is set by the minimum and maximum of "area" values at 0.5). Do you think it is possible to do that with ggplot.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: *"plot "area" from each "Time" value with it own gradient range "* I'm not sure I understand; that would mean you have as many different gradient scales as there are `Time` rows in your heatmap. That makes no sense to me. It's probably better to scale your data by row (i.e. `Time`), in which case the gradient would encode differences in units of standard deviation for every row (`Time`)?

Comment: Make the words (with exact spellings) in your question match the names of items in your example.

Comment: @ Maurits, yes, that mean there are as many different gradient scale in the plot. It seems your suggestion is what I am looking for. Could you please make it more clear. Thank you!

Comment: @HoangLe Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scale `area` entries by `Time`, so you end up with standardised `area` Z scores that characterise the difference from a zero mean in units of standard deviation per `Time`.

```
set.seed(2017);
df <- data.frame(
    time = as.factor(rep(0.5:9.5, each = 10)),
    roi = rep(1:10, 10),
    area = runif(100, 5.0, 7.5))

 library(tidyverse);
 df %>%
     mutate(time = factor(time, levels = rev(levels(time)))) %>%
     group_by(time) %>%
     mutate(area = scale(area)) %>%
     ggplot(aes(x=factor(roi), y=time, fill = area)) +
         theme_minimal() +
         coord_fixed(ratio=1) +
         geom_tile(colour = "white", width = 1.0, height = 1) +
         scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red")
```

[image]

Note that `area` is now a Z score; for example a value of `-2` means that this particular entry is 2 standard deviations below the mean `area` value for this particular `Time`.

Comment: @ Maurits, Thank you so much for your answer. That is what I am looking for.